# jQuery live problem: in select list filter function, live doesn't work with keyup event

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script, which is filtering an html select list.
It works fine when I use the keyup event, but I recently tried to use instead the `live("keyup"`, but it doesn't work.

Here is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="Description" content="" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="Distribution" content="Global" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>Select list filter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
//simple keyup
    ;(function($) {
        $.fn.selectFilter = function() {

            var sel = $(this);
            $(this).after("<input style='display: block;' type='text' />");
            $(this).css("display", "block");
            if($(this).attr("size")<2)
            {
                $(this).attr("size", "3");
            }
            $(this).next("input[type='text']").keyup(function(){
                sel.children('option').hide();
                var a = new Array();
                var txt = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                sel.children('option').each(function(i, selected){
                    var pattern=new RegExp(txt);
                    var value = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                    if(pattern.test(value))
                    {
                        $(selected).show();
                    }
                });
            }); 
        };
        })(jQuery);

//live keyup    
    ;(function($) {
        $.fn.liveSelectFilter = function() {

            var sel = $(this);
            $(this).after("<input style='display: block;' type='text' />");
            $(this).css("display", "block");
            if($(this).attr("size")<2)
            {
                $(this).attr("size", "3");
            }
            $(this).next("input[type='text']").live("keyup", function(){
                sel.children('option').hide();
                var a = new Array();
                var txt = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                sel.children('option').each(function(i, selected){
                    var pattern=new RegExp(txt);
                    var value = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                    if(pattern.test(value))
                    {
                        $(selected).show();
                    }
                });
            }); 
        };
        })(jQuery);
    

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#select-list").selectFilter();
        jQuery("#live-select-list").liveSelectFilter();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
Keyup: 
<select id="select-list" size="5" name='test' style="width:200px">
  <option value='1'>John Smith</option>
  <option value='2'>John Doe</option>
  <option value='3'>Jason Bradley</option>

  <option value='4'>Bob Smith</option>
  <option value='5'>Jane Doe</option>
  <option value='6'>David White</option>
  <option value='7'>Neal Johnson</option>
  <option value='8'>Richard Bradman</option>
</select>
<br /><br />Live keyup: 

<select id="live-select-list" size="5" name='test' style="width:200px">
  <option value='1'>John Smith</option>
  <option value='2'>John Doe</option>
  <option value='3'>Jason Bradley</option>
  <option value='4'>Bob Smith</option>
  <option value='5'>Jane Doe</option>
  <option value='6'>David White</option>

  <option value='7'>Neal Johnson</option>
  <option value='8'>Richard Bradman</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what browser are you in?  This seems to work fine for me, I tried Chrome, Safari and FF http://jsfiddle.net/vz6Xv/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) works with selectors and not specified elements.

Quoting from the docs

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which **match the current selector**, now and in the future.

and

> DOM traversal methods are not
>   supported for finding elements to send
>   to .live(). Rather, the .live() method
>   should always be called directly after
>   a selector, as in the example above.

So you should change the way you bind the live event to

```
$(this.selector + " + input[type='text']").live("keyup", function(){
```

`this.selector` will return the original selector used and the `+ input[type='text']` is the [next adjacent selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)

**live at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/u9uhV/